# Como usar el Google Analytics en un proyecto NUXT

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt

Tengo un sitio web con Nuxt y quiero ponerle el Script de Google Analytics.

He descargado el módulo vue-gtag

```
yarn add vue-gtag
```

He creado un archivo en plugins/gtag.js con el código

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueGtag from 'vue-gtag';
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
   Vue.use (VueGtag, {
       config: {id: 'UA-XXXXXX-1'},
       appName: 'Archery', 
  });
}
```

Y lo llamo desde nuxt.config.js

```
plugins: [{
    src: './plugins/gtag.js', 
    mode: 'client'
}]
```

Compilándolo con yarn generate no da error, pero tampoco se crea código en ningún archivo.

¿Alguien ha usado gtag en Nuxt y puede ayudarme?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si usas Nuxt, puedes usar el plugin @nuxtjs/google-analytics

https://google-analytics.nuxtjs.org/setup/#installation

Es facil de instalar y configurar, espero que te ayude.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).